# What sector is Photos folder on hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, photos, data-recovery

I'm trying to recover some deleted photos from my Mac, but the problem is that I'm not able to select what folder it should be looking in.

I am, however, able to select what sector it should be looking in and I was wondering if you guys know what sector the pictures folder is in?.

Answer (score 4):

Photos are not stored on a particular sector on your hard drive, the sectors are maintained by the operating system and the hard drive itself. I would suggest scanning the entire drive for deleted files as your best chance of finding the files you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the Pictures folder is under `/Users/<your username>/Pictures/`. Some other third-party photo apps might be under `/Users/<your username>/Documents/<app name>`.

[image]

Comment: I would say the sector is lower level than the folder structure. Especially when you're trying to recover deleted data.